# Brahmasutra Lingam and its types

Tags: scripture, shiva, shiva-lingam, vedic-rituals, pranapratishtha

I found some lingams with lines carved on them but for some lingams there are no lines carved. I've heard that the lingam which has these lines is more auspicious than the regular ones. So I'd like to know about the Brahmasutra lingam, it's types and the difference of paddhathi in consecrating this lingam in temples. Moreover it'd be helpful if you could explain other types of lingams which are classified based on the type of material the lingam is made of, the sutras on the lingam, and the type of consecration done for the lingam (if applicable).

Comment: The gāṇapatya, daivika and ārṣa liṅgas don't have brahma-sūtra mark.